# Python 2.7: Unable to catch exception

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, try-except

I have the following code:

```
def distributeMembersFile(members):
    for node in members:
        node = node.strip() # Strip trailing \n
        if node == socket.hostname(): # No need to send the file to itself
            continue
        conn = None
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
            s.connect((node, port))
            # TODO: Can possibly update the list of members here as well
            s.sendall('DWLD')
            s.recv(4)
        except socket.error, msg:
            logging.info(msg)
        finally:
            if s:
                s.close()
```

Now, my question is that even though s.connect() is in a try except socket.error block, that exception is not being caught. I see the following traceback on console:

```
    s.connect((node, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
error: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

Interestingly, in other places I have the same try except socket.error block, and this particular (Connection refused) error is caught as:

```
INFO (111, 'Connection refused')
```

Above was printed by the logging.info function in except block. The only way I see right now to catch this exception is to use a 'bare' except, which is not considered a very good thing. Also, I found it peculiar that the error on the console is not being presented as

> socket.error: (111, 'Connection refused')

Instead, it just says

```
error: (111. 'Connection refused')
```

missing the leading word 'socket'. What could be the reason behing the exception not being caught?

Comment: Your call is `s.connect((node, LISTEN_PORT))` but the error shows the line `s.connect((node, port))`.  Are you sure the error is being raised where you think it is?

Comment: Where's `port` variable defined which is used in the `s.connect((node, port))` call?

Comment: I edited the question. The actual function call in distributeMembersFile is a wrapper over s.connect. I have removed the wrapper for clarity. The line number in the traceback points to this very line

Comment: @martineau: port is a global variable.

Comment: Maybe it's another exception type. Try using a generic `except Exception:` clause and `print sys.exc_info()[:2]` when one happens.